# If an array name is not a variable and not a lvalue, what is it?

Tags: c

In K&R's The C Programming Language's 5.3 Pointers and Arrays

> A
> pointer  is  a  variable,  so  pa=a  and  pa++  are  legal.  But  **an  array  name  is  not  a  variable**;
> constructions like a=pa and a++ are illegal.

In https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/understanding-and-using/9781449344535/ch04.html#DifferencesBetweenArraysAndPointersSection:

> The pointer `pv` is an lvalue. An lvalue denotes the term used on the
> lefthand side of an assignment operator. An lvalue must be capable of
> being modified. **An array name such as `vector` is not an lvalue and
> cannot be modified.** The address assigned to an array cannot be changed
> . A pointer can be assigned a new value and reference a different
> section of memory.
>
> Consider the following:
>
> ```
> pv = pv + 1;
> vector = vector + 1; // Syntax error
> ```
>
> We cannot modify vector, only its contents. However, the expression
> vector+1 is fine, as demonstrated below:
>
> ```
> pv = vector + 1;
> ```

If an array name is not a variable and not a lvalue,  what is an array name? A constant?

Comment: It's a non-modifiable lvalue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array is not an assignable lvalue, which means it can't appear on the left side of an assignment or otherwise be modified.  Array elements, however, are assignable lvalues.

EDIT:

An lvalue has an address and can be referenced in multiple places.  So something like `const int foo = 12;` is still an lvalue, but not a modifiable one.

In contrast, a constant such as 7 or "hello" is an rvalue, meaning it cannot be referenced beyond that expression.  Expressions such as `a + b` or `a + 1` are also rvalues.

Comment: (1) is an array name a constant? (2) What is the relation between a constant and a non-assignable lvalue? Is a constant a non-assignable lvalue? Is a non-assignable lvalue? Or is a constant an assignable lvalue?

Comment: @Tim A constant such as `7` or `"hello"` is an rvalue, meaning it cannot be referenced beyond that expression.  An lvalue, on the other hand, has an address and can be referenced in multiple places.

Comment: Thanks. Is a constant always an rvalue?

Comment: @Tim Yes, constants are always rvalues, and all variables are lvalues (though not all are assignable).

Comment: Thanks. What do rvalues include besides constants? Are "literals" and "constants" the same concept?

Comment: @Tim Yes, two different names for the same thing.

Comment: @dbush is `foo` in `const int foo = 12;` not a constant? @Tim expressions, such as `a * b` or `bar()` are also rvalues. According to C11§6.3.2.1 note 64: *The name ‘‘lvalue’’ comes originally from the assignment expression `E1 = E2`, in which the left operand `E1` is required to be a (modifiable) lvalue. It is perhaps better considered as representing an object ‘‘locator value’’. What is sometimes called ‘‘rvalue’’ is in this International Standard described as the ‘‘value of an expression’’.*

Comment: @Tim `x + 3` is an rvalue. You can do `var = x + 3;`, but you can't do `x + 3 = var;`

Comment: @Kninnug `foo` is actually an unmodifiable lvalue.

Comment: @dbush Is an array name still an lvalue, but not a modifiable lvalue? (See my update to my post)

Comment: @Tim Correct, an array name is an lvalue, but not a modifiable lvalue.